# Hover Images on Mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, hover

I have a hover image feature on my website that has been built with CARGO Collective. I have added the hover feature to the CSS which works fine, however these hover images don't appear on mobile. My question is how can I add to the CSS to make them tappable image links on mobile but remain on hover on the desktop version?

Here is where the hover CSS appears on the site:

```
.hover-title {
    display: inline;
    pointer-events: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hover-title {
color: #FFB000;
}

body:not(.mobile) .hover-title:hover + .hover-image {
    visibility: visible;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.hover-image {
    visibility: hidden;
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index:5;
    pointer-events: none;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;

/* Change width and height to scale images */
    width: 90vw;
    height: 90vh;
}

.hover-image img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    max-height: 100% !important;
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is also mentioned at http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp ; you can achieve what you want to (tap on mobile, hover on desktop), if you mention the `:active` selector before the hover `:selector`

Answer (score 0):

the `visibility: hidden;` will hide the images unless you unhide them with a greater specificity. Since you want the images to appear on both mobile and desktop (but with different styling), get rid of the `visibility` properties, and use a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries) to change the styling between desktop and mobile.